# Minecraft keep crashing, Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

SO i wanted to get to feel that nostalgia but i have been REALLY annoyed by an unpleasant issue. any help its hugely apreciated!
My specs:

- IntelCorei7-2600 3.6 GHz
- 8GB Ram
- Windows 10 pro
- No graphics card (hope that this its not the issue, even tho im pretty sure it can be)

Here is the error log

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Hey, that tickles! Hehehe!

Time: 11/04/19 20:14
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.IllegalStateException: GLFW error 65542: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
    at cgd.b(SourceFile:218)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1649)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1827)
    at cgd.<init>(SourceFile:99)
    at cgc.a(SourceFile:79)
    at cft.am(SourceFile:439)
    at cft.a(SourceFile:380)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at cgd.b(SourceFile:218)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallbackI.callback(GLFWErrorCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokePPPP(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.nglfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1649)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(GLFW.java:1827)
    at cgd.<init>(SourceFile:99)
    at cgc.a(SourceFile:79)
    at cft.am(SourceFile:439)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at cft.a(SourceFile:380)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.13.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_201, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 34848312 bytes (33 MB) / 202657792 bytes (193 MB) up to 6991118336 bytes (6667 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmn128M -Xmx6680M -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    Launched Version: 1.13.2
    LWJGL: 3.1.6 build 14
    OpenGL: NO CONTEXT
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem caused because `Core i7-2600` has `HD Graphics 2000` in it but the minimum graphic requirement for Minecraft Java Edition is `Intel HD Graphics 4000`